# EntitiyFramework retrieving and storing back entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've got a problem with `EntityFramework`. In my app there is an async `GetCollections` method, which will return a `Task>:

```
public async Task<List<MyCollection>> GetCollections() {,

 IQueryable<MyCollection> query;
 query = ...;
 var result = await query.ToListAsync();
 return result;
}
```

Problem is the `ToListAsync()` call, which creates (it looks like) a copy of the entities. When I later modify some of the returned collections and call `DbContext.SaveChanges()` an exception is thrown, because multiple entities with same primary key are to store. So my question is, what can i do about it?

Edit:

Okay I have rewritten this method to return an `IQueriable` instead. This fixes the problem with multiple entities with same primary key, but when looping through the IQueriable and modifying entities, an exception is thrown because a second connection to the Database cannot be instantiated. Is there any other type I can return, which fixes this problem?

Comment: Why do you need to return the result as a `List<T>`? Why can you not use the `IQueryable<T>` it returns for you?

Comment: How do you modify entities?